# Is there a jsonb array overlap function for postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Am not able to extract and compare two arrays from jsonb in postgres to do an overlap check. Is there a working function for this?

Example in people_favorite_color table:

```
{
    "person_id":1,
    "favorite_colors":["red","orange","yellow"]
}
{
    "person_id":2,
    "favorite_colors":["yellow","green","blue"]
}
{
    "person_id":3,
    "favorite_colors":["black","white"]
}
```

Array overlap postgres tests:

```
select 
p1.json_data->>'person_id',
p2.json_data->>'person_id',
p1.json_data->'favorite_colors' && p2.json_data->'favorite_colors'
from people_favorite_color p1 join people_favorite_color p2 on (1=1)
where p1.json_data->>'person_id' < p2.json_data->>'person_id'
```

Expected results:

```
p1.id;p2.id;likes_same_color
1;2;t
1;3;f
2;3;f
```

--edit--
Attempting to cast to text[] results in an error:

```
select
('{
        "person_id":3,
        "favorite_colors":["black","white"]
}'::jsonb->>'favorite_colors')::text[];

ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["black", "white"]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

Comment: Try casting the result of `p1.json_data->'favorite_colors'` to `text[]` then you should be able to use the usual array overlaps operator.

Comment: Please, use [JSONLint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to validate json values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name edited the question to fix format and include results from casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_agg()` and `jsonb_array_elements_text()` to convert jsonb array to text array:

```
with the_data as (
    select id, array_agg(color) colors
    from (
        select json_data->'person_id' id, color
        from 
            people_favorite_color, 
            jsonb_array_elements_text(json_data->'favorite_colors') color
        ) sub
    group by 1
    ) 
select p1.id, p2.id, p1.colors && p2.colors like_same_colors
from the_data p1
join the_data p2 on p1.id < p2.id
order by 1, 2;

 id | id | like_same_colors 
----+----+------------------
 1  | 2  | t
 1  | 3  | f
 2  | 3  | f
(3 rows)
```